# Constraint on the sum of parameters in Keras Layer

Tags: keras, constraints, keras-layer, activation-function

I want to add custom constraints on the parameters of a layer. 
I write a custom activation layer with two trainable parameters a and b s.t:
`activation_fct = a*fct() + b*fct()`.
I need to have the sum of the parameters (a+b) equal to 1 but I don't know how to write such a constraint. 
Can you give me some advices ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a single weight instead of two, and use this custom constraint:

```
import keras.backend as K

class Between_0_1(keras.constraints.Constraint):
    def __call__(self, w):
        return K.clip(w, 0, 1)
```

Then when building the weights, build only a and use the constraints.

```
def build(self, input_shape):
    self.a = self.add_weight(name='weight_a', 
                                  shape=(1,),
                                  initializer='uniform',
                                  constraint = Between_0_1(), 
                                  trainable=True)

    #if you want to start as 0.5
    K.set_value(self.a, [0.5])

    self.built = True
```

In `call`, `b = 1-a`:

```
def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
    #do stuff
    ....

    return (self.a * something) +  ((1-self.a)*another_thing)
```

---

You can alsto try @MatusDubrava `softmax` approach, but in this case your weights need to have shape `(2,)`, and no constraint:

```
def build(self, input_shape):
    self.w = self.add_weight(name='weights', 
                              shape=(2,),
                              initializer='zeros',
                              trainable=True)
    self.build = True

def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
    w = K.softmax(self.w)

    #do stuff
    ....

    return (w[0] * something ) + (w[1] * another_thing)
```

Answer (score 3):

Two approaches come to my mind.

First one is to lock one of the parameters, let's say `b` and make only the other one (`a` in this case) trainable. Then you can compute `b` as follows

```
b = 1 - a
```

The second approach could be making both `a` and `b` trainable and transform them via `softmax` function. Softmax function will make sure that their sum is always 1.

```
from scipy.special import softmax

a = 0.12
b = 0.3
w1, w2 = softmax([a, b])

print(f'w1: {w1}, w2: {w2}, w1 + w2: {w1 + w2}')
```

This will produce

> w1: 0.45512110762641994, w2: 0.5448788923735801, w1 + w2: 1.0

And once you have `w1` and `w2`, you can use them in the mentioned formula instead of `a` and `b`.

```
activation_fct = w1 * fct() + w2 * fct()
```

Comment: Great answer, but use `keras.backend.softmax`, while the weights should be a single tensor with shape `(2,)`. Then `a=weights[0]` and `b=weights[1]`.

Comment: Thanks Matus Dubrava and Daniel Möller. I decided to use keras.backend.softmax, and I change the weights as Daniel said ( single tensor ). It works !