# Multiple Constraints tensorflow variable

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I have a weight variable of dimension (100,1).
I want to impose 2 constraint so that it behaves like a probability distribution.
All values should be non-negative and all values should sum to one.
How to impose both these constraints?
I tried this putting both of them in an array, but it expects only 1 constraint-

```
self.w = self.add_weight(name="Estimated_Returns_Trainable_Weight_Vector",
                             shape=(returns_vector[0], returns_vector[1]),
                             initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(minval=0,maxval=1/returns_vector[0]),
                             constraint = [tf.keras.constraints.non_neg(),tf.keras.constraints.unit_norm(axis = 0)],
                             trainable=True,
                             )
```

Comment: Maybe you shold write a custom constraint

Comment: Did you find a solution? Maybe using a softmax function on the weight variable gets you what you need (all weights non-neg, and they sum up to one). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60077925/9848704)  answer seems to work (albeit they are not using a `constraint`).